# WPF DataGrid - Apply style to whichever column is displayed as first with DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

In a `DataGrid`, I need to apply a style based on a certain condition implemented in my data context. But it has to be applied to the cells of the **first column only**.

Since a user is allowed to reorder columns, I don't know which is the first one in advance. So I tried to implement it at the `CellStyle` level, with a condition on the `DisplayIndex`:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="0" />
```

I put it into a MultiDataTrigger with the condition on the data, that is:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding IsInEvidence}" Value="False" />
```

`IsInEvidence` is a `bool` property in my row-level view model. If I leave this only, it works fine, but it gets applied to **all** the cells.

```
<DataGrid Items={Binding Items}/>
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
               <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding IsInEvidence}" Value="False" />
                  <Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}" Value="0" />
               </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>

   <!-- Column defintions and so on -->

</DataGrid>
```

Comment: you can also use `RelativeSource Self` instead of `AncestoryType`. anyway, it should work as it is. did you try to debug it to see what is the value of `Column.DisplayIndex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `Condition` binding to use `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`, then it works.

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding Column.DisplayIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="0"/>
```